# Restrict database connection to application running from a network share using TNSNames

Tags: database, oracle, networking

I have a somewhat unique(though probably not) situation. I have users that access a 3rd party application over a network share. This application connects to an Oracle database. The problem is, we have Production, QA, Test, and Dev databases and separate shares/applications for each, but the application doesn't care what database it connects to. So I have users launching the Test application for testing and they log into the Production database. This causes major issues.

Is there any way to restrict what database they log into by network share?

I tried using TNSNames on each server that houses each version of the application and that works great...if they are running it on the server, but since all users have Oracle installed on their local machines and they run the application from a network share, their Oracle takes over and allows them to connect to any database (using LDAP).

Comment: Can you launch the application through a batch/shell script that sets `TNS_ADMIN` to the location of the `tnsnames.ora` on that share, to it uses that instead of the user's local file?

Comment: I will give that a try.